# atexit not triggering after sys.exit() is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to implement some basic close out tasks for an automation script I have written in python using pyautogui.  I open a program and click certain buttons every day to create daily reports.  But if something goes wrong, I need it to close the program it is using.

I tried using atexit.register, but it didn't seem to run when I trigger sys.exit().  So I wrote a test script to verify that it was triggering, and it isn't.

```
import atexit as a
import sys

def closeout():
    print("atexit triggered, closing out")

print("starting program")
print("Registering closeout with atexit")
a.register(closeout)
print(r"triggering sys.exit()")
sys.exit()
```

it should print out the following:

```
"starting program"
"Registering closeout with atexit"
"triggering sys.exit()"
"atexit triggered, closing out"
```

but I don't get the last line.

Any thoughts?  I'm running 3.7.2 if it matters.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with your code (I do get the "closing out" message). Can you elaborate a bit on how you're running your script?

Comment: I'm running the script from the idle launcher.  I have the script open in the editor and press F5.  I also get the error if I import the script into the idle launcher

Comment: Try running the script from the command-line. Sounds like a probable IDLE issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "run module" from IDLE, it uses the [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) builtin to build a code object from the associated file, and then runs it with `exec`. The process that runs the code doesn't exit, and `SystemExit` is caught and silently ignored in the IDLE interpreter - otherwise a script that included it would cause IDLE to quit! - so the `atexit` handler isn't run.

Furthermore, the default build of IDLE is configured to delete any register `atexit` functions when exiting, so your handler isn't run when IDLE itself eventually exits. (See the [exit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9e30fbac019d9c0a31d444a711e845c7e883caf5/Lib/idlelib/run.py#L270) function in the cpython repo.)